# How to Implement Custom SwiftUI ScrollTargetBehavior for Center-Snapping Cells in a ScrollView?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, snapping

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI project where I need to create a custom vertical ScrollView. The requirement is for the cells within this ScrollView to snap to the center of the view when the user stops scrolling. I understand that SwiftUI's ScrollView provides some level of customization through the `.scrollTargetBehavior(_:)` modifier, but the documentation and examples I've found don't quite cover this specific case.

I've tried using the basic scrollTargetBehavior `.viewAligned`, but the snapping behavior doesn't include the snapping effect I'm looking for. I'm aware that UIKit provides more granular control over scrolling behavior with UICollectionView and custom layout attributes, but I'm aiming to achieve this purely within the SwiftUI.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of a working example, I'm going to use many instances of this as the content of the `ScrollView`:

```
struct Card: View {
    let i: Int

    var body: some View {
        let suit = ["heart", "spade", "diamond", "club"][i / 13]
        let rank = i == 9 ? "10" : String("A23456789_JQK".dropFirst(i % 13).prefix(1))
        let color = (i / 13).isMultiple(of: 2) ? Color.red : Color.black
        let label = VStack { Text(rank); Image(systemName: "suit.\(suit).fill") }.padding(12)

        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .circular)
            .fill(.white)
            .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) { label }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) { label.rotationEffect(.degrees(180)) }
            .foregroundStyle(color)
            .font(.system(size: 40))
            .overlay {
                Canvas { gc, size in
                    gc.translateBy(x: 0.5 * size.width, y: 0.5 * size.height)
                    gc.stroke(
                        Path {
                            $0.move(to: .init(x: -10, y: -10))
                            $0.addLine(to: .init(x: 10, y: 10))
                            $0.move(to: .init(x: 10, y: -10))
                            $0.addLine(to: .init(x: -10, y: 10))
                        },
                        with: .color(color)
                    )
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .compositingGroup()
            .shadow(radius: 1.5, x: 0, y: 0.5)
    }
}
```

This draws a sort of playing card with a cross in the center. The cross will make it easy to see whether the `ScrollView` centers a card when it stops scrolling.

Let's start with a basic `ScrollView` setup containing the full deck of cards:

```
struct BasicContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< 52) { i in
                    Card(i: i)
                        .frame(height: 500)
                }
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 1)
                .foregroundStyle(.green)
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: scroll view showing the ace of hearts and a little of the two of hearts, with a green horizontal line centered vertically]

The green line is at the vertical center of the `ScrollView`. We can tell that a card is centered if the card's cross lines up with the green line.

To make the `ScrollView` stop scrolling with a centered card, we need to write a custom implementation of [`ScrollTargetBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrolltargetbehavior#). By reading the documentation (and in particular the documentation of [`ScrollTargetBehaviorContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrolltargetbehaviorcontext) and [`ScrollTarget`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrolltarget)), we can infer that our custom `ScrollTargetBehavior` needs access to the frames of the card views, in the `ScrollView`s coordinate space.

To collect those frames, we need to use [SwiftUI's “preference” system](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferences). First, we need a type to collect the card frames:

```
struct CardFrames: Equatable {
    var frames: [Int: CGRect] = [:]
}
```

Next, we need a custom implementation of [the `PreferenceKey` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferencekey). We might as well use the `CardFrames` type as the key:

```
extension CardFrames: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: Self { .init() }

    static func reduce(value: inout Self, nextValue: () -> Self) {
        value.frames.merge(nextValue().frames) { $1 }
    }
}
```

We need to add a `@State` property to store the collected frames:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    //  Add this property to ContentView
    @State var cardFrames: CardFrames = .init()

    var body: some View {
    ...
```

We also need to define a `NamedCoordinateSpace` for the `ScrollView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var cardFrames: CardFrames = .init()

    //  Add this property to ContentView
    private static let geometry = NamedCoordinateSpace.named("geometry")

    var body: some View {
    ...
```

Next we need to apply that coordinate space to the content of the `ScrollView`, by adding a `coordinateSpace` modifier to the `LazyVStack`:

```
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< 52) { i in
                    Card(i: i)
                        .frame(height: 500)
                }
            }

            //  Add this modifier to LazyVStack
            .coordinateSpace(Self.geometry)
        }
```

To read the frame of a `Card` and set the preference, we use a common SwiftUI pattern: add a `background` containing a `GeometryReader` containing a `Color.clear` with a `preference` modifier:

```
                    Card(i: i)
                        .frame(height: 500)
                        //  Add this modifier to LazyVStack
                        .background {
                            GeometryReader { proxy in
                                Color.clear
                                    .preference(
                                        key: CardFrames.self,
                                        value: CardFrames(
                                            frames: [i: proxy.frame(in: Self.geometry)]
                                        )
                                    )
                            }
                        }
```

Now we can read out the `CardFrames` preference and store it in the `@State` property, by using the `onPreferenceChange` modifier:

```
        ScrollView {
           ...
        }
        .overlay {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 1)
                .foregroundStyle(.green)
        }
        //  Add this modifier to ScrollView
        .onPreferenceChange(CardFrames.self) { cardFrames = $0 }
```

That is all the code to collect the card frames and make them available in the `cardFrames` property.

Now we're ready to write a custom `ScrollTargetBehavior`. Our custom behavior adjusts the `ScrollTarget` so that its midpoint is the midpoint of the nearest card:

```
struct CardFramesScrollTargetBehavior: ScrollTargetBehavior {
    var cardFrames: CardFrames

    func updateTarget(_ target: inout ScrollTarget, context: TargetContext) {
        let yProposed = target.rect.midY
        guard let nearestEntry = cardFrames
            .frames
            .min(by: { ($0.value.midY - yProposed).magnitude < ($1.value.midY - yProposed).magnitude })
        else { return }
        target.rect.origin.y = nearestEntry.value.midY - 0.5 * target.rect.size.height
    }
}
```

Finally, we use the `scrollTargetBehavior` modifier to apply our custom behavior to the `ScrollView`:

```
        ScrollView {
            ...
        }
        //  Add this modifier to ScrollView
        .scrollTargetBehavior(CardFramesScrollTargetBehavior(cardFrames: cardFrames))
        .overlay {
            ...
```

[image: demo of scroll target behavior]

I noticed that, when scrolling back up and landing on the 3♥︎ card, it's not quite centered. I think that's a SwiftUI bug.

Here's the final `ContentView` with all the additions:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cardFrames: CardFrames = .init()

    private static let geometry = NamedCoordinateSpace.named("geometry")

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< 52) { i in
                    Card(i: i)
                        .frame(height: 500)
                        .background {
                            GeometryReader { proxy in
                                Color.clear
                                    .preference(
                                        key: CardFrames.self,
                                        value: CardFrames(
                                            frames: [i: proxy.frame(in: Self.geometry)]
                                        )
                                    )
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .coordinateSpace(Self.geometry)
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(CardFramesScrollTargetBehavior(cardFrames: cardFrames))
        .overlay {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 1)
                .foregroundStyle(.green)
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(CardFrames.self) { cardFrames = $0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you Rob! This was very informative. 
Question - why didn't we need to use .scrollTargetLayout() on the LazyVStack? The documentation has me to believe you need that to have views even considered for scrollTargetBehavior

Comment: [The `scrollTargetLayout` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scrolltargetlayout(isenabled:)) says “This modifier works together with the [`ViewAlignedScrollTargetBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewalignedscrolltargetbehavior) to ensure that scroll views align to view based content.” Since my answer does not use `ViewAlignedScrollTargetBehavior`, there is no reason for it to use `scrollTargetLayout`.